How can I get Instagram username from user_id
I have a user id, for example: 56125243722. How can I get the username just from the id without using any authorization like Bearer or Instagram API keys. I tried a lot of things and none of them worked. /api/v1/users/xxx/info/ requires auth now and others too. Does anyone know any endpoint that can suit my need?

There is no official API for this, that you could use without any form of authentication.

i don't need official api, i can use the app api for it i just couldn't find any endpoint on the app

https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/{user_id}?access_token={page_access_token}

You missed the "without using any authorization like Bearer or Instagram API keys."
